# How to make MPAndroidChart RadarChart round

Tags: java, android, mpandroidchart, radar-chart

I would like to present some Values inside a Radar Chart.
Long-time I was working with AndroidPlot which works great but it doesn't support Radar charts.
So I swapped to MPAndroidCharts.
But MPCharts only supports angular RadarCharts by default.

I found the following Link in the Issues, but there is no Code given
https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/issues/1446

Another Stack Overflow Entry I found is this, but I can't combine it with MPAndroid Charts
[Radar Chart for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20357544/radar-chart-for-android)

At the Android Charts Library:
https://github.com/limccn/Android-Charts
rounded Charts are mentioned, but I can't find the according Class in Code

Is there already a solution to make MPAndroidCharts RadarCharts round,
or any other Library that supports rounded RadarCharts.
Thanks for Help

Answer (score 2):

go to `RadarChartRenderer` class.
and edit the method inside class like below:

```
protected void drawDataSet(Canvas c, IRadarDataSet dataSet, int mostEntries) {

  ..........................
  ..........................

        mRenderPaint.setStrokeWidth(dataSet.getLineWidth());
        mRenderPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mRenderPaint.setDither(true);                   
        mRenderPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);  
        mRenderPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND); 
        mRenderPaint.setPathEffect(new CornerPathEffect(30) );  
        mRenderPaint.setAntiAlias(true); 

  ............................
  ............................
}
```

my results like:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

As mention in the issue link, you can implement it by yourself, just see https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/c1f6fcebf0c3516e067b34312b283189f909bde5/MPChartLib/src/main/java/com/github/mikephil/charting/charts/RadarChart.java as a reference,

1. write your `RoundRadarChart` class to extend the `RadarChart`
2. write your `RoundRadarChartRenderer`, `YAxisRendererRoundRadarChart` and `XAxisRendererRoundRadarChart` to extend the RadarChart ones, mainly you should to override the `drawXXX` functions
3. use your new renderer classes in your chart class to replace the RadarChart renderers

You need to re-caculate the factory of drawing lines, points and labels

And about the `Android-Charts` project, you may have a look at https://github.com/limccn/Android-Charts/tree/master/src/src/cn/limc/androidcharts/view. Not sure if the `RoundChart` is what you want.