# How to achieve the design in the ANDROID?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

How to achieve the attached IMAGE design in the ANDROID?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please look at these link to ask a question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: what is that? why u don't use a PNG?

Comment: @feridok need to display from xml design

Comment: I think you can't create that image with xml (layer list and shapes). what about vectors?

Comment: @feridok Thanks a lot feridok, The design in the layout is the primary requirement, The Image is the last option

Comment: check this link may useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20357544/radar-chart-for-android

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ImageView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView) to display the image.

```
<ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/your_image" />
```

Don't forget to put the image to `drawable` folder.

Comment: Thanks a lot John Joe, The design in the layout is the primary requirement, The Image is the last option.